# SI8751 isolated MOSFET driver and MOSFET NVD5C668NL

Tags: mosfet, switching, digital-isolator

I need help for my very first application with a power MOSFET. The goal is "simple": create a SSR for switching a generic DC load with variable power supply from 5 to 48 V and max. 25 A. Isolation isn't a request but I would use it. Switch must be high side.

I studied the Silabs [Si875x](https://www.skyworksinc.com/-/media/Skyworks/SL/documents/public/data-sheets/Si8751-2.pdf) isolated driver. I am not sure if this driver can be used for switching the MOSFET. If I'm not wrong, the switching time is very long (milliseconds).
I need help to find a solution that allows me to speed up the MOSFET switching.

Answer (score 2):

You would need a charge pump for high side switch. If you need a switch to be fast as well, then you should consider a DC/DC converter. But unfortunately, with DC/DC you will have some loss, since it will always be on waiting for your turn on command.

If you further need an isolation you can put isolated gate driver, but still you will need a kind of isolated power supply.

EDIT:
If you want just a simple SSR, then the speed shouldn't be your priority. In such case the simplest way is to use photovoltaic coupler which will produce enough voltage to turn on the MOSFET, but this is slow. Look for VOM1271, what you get is the galvanic isolation + gate driver in single IC.

Comment: Thanks Marko for the quick reply and suggestion. I read the VOM1271 datasheet but I have always the same doubt: switching speed isn't a problem for me, the on-off-on.. cycle time is measured in seconds, but I am looking infos about the turn on and turn off time Which is the peak current that VOM1271 can source/sync to/from the gate. You say that whit the VOM1271 the turn on or off time is too slow but for my application hundreds of milliseconds isn't a problem but how estimate the peak power dissipate during turn on/off.

Comment: I meant slow in terms of large rise time, when the MOSFET will produce major power loss. IMO the only way to calculate is to make a prototype board. You should use a MOSFET with smalle gate charge as possible. Check this out: http://www.eenewspower.com/content/variable-hv-power-supply-employs-photovoltaic-optocoupler . IMO there shouldn't be a problem if you cycle in seconds, as you can see the turn off is almost immediately, while the turn on takes a while to charge the gate.

Comment: I think it should work very good with NVD5C668NL, since it has low threshold voltage Vgs(th). I wouldn't place zener diodes parallel to the gate, since they increase the capacitance.  A simple calc for turn on power loss is : Id * Vd * 0.5 * t_r (t_r = 90us, Vd=48v, Id= 25A) =  0.54W per switch on event.